# Basic cron job issue

Tags: javascript, html, insert, cron, jobs

I have a particular script in my HTML file that I want to run every 24 hours using a cron job. My question is what path do I enter into my hostinger (host) command.

Do I enter php /path/to/index.php because won't that run my whole code every 24 hours, I want to know how to run a specific script every 24 hours.

Attached is my code, thank you in advance !!

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">

</div>

<div id="maincontent">
<h1>Rumours</h1>




<table id="myTable" width"100%">

  <tr>
    <th width="30%">From</th>
    <th width="30%">Player</th>   
    <th width="40%">Price</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></br></td>
    <td></br></td>    
    <td></br></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>

// Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
</script>



</div>

<div id="rightbar">
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Running a html/js file periodically does nothing because the calculated stuff is tied to the session. If you want to do some operations and save the results, you need to use PHP for instance.

Comment: You use php for server side (apache for ex) or js (node)? From your question I think you use php, and in that case... js is client side. Running it won't help you (not running the code you posted anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cURL or wget in your cron job script, with localhost as the hostname in the URL that you fetch.  That way, you'll be invoking your web page via the web server (typically Apache, but not necessarily), which will run PHP.

You'll have to set up a particular webpage/URL to do what you want the script to accomplish every 24 hours.

For example, your cron script, in website-cron.sh, could be:

```
#! /bin/sh

/usr/bin/curl --silent --show-error http://localhost/cron-script.php/parameters
```

You could put this in your crontab file using `crontab -e` and entering this line to run the script at 3:00am every day:

```
0 3 * * *   /path/to/website-cron.sh
```